# Ubuntu 17.04 Failed to start samba.service: Unit samba.service is masked

Tags: samba, file-sharing

```
corrado@corrado-zesty2:~$ sudo service samba start
[sudo] password for corrado: 
Failed to start samba.service: Unit samba.service is masked.
corrado@corrado-zesty2:~$ sudo systemctl unmask samba.service
corrado@corrado-zesty2:~$ sudo service samba start
Failed to start samba.service: Unit samba.service is masked.
corrado@corrado-zesty2:~$ sudo apt-get install samba
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
samba is already the newest version (2:4.4.5+dfsg-2ubuntu6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 108 not upgraded.
corrado@corrado-zesty2:~$ inxi 
CPU~Dual core Intel Core i3-4130 (-HT-MCP-) speed/max~802/3400 MHz Kernel~4.9.0-1-generic x86_64 Up~1:08 Mem~998.4/7862.7MB HDD~1000.2GB(1.6% used) Procs~232 Client~Shell inxi~2.3.4  
corrado@corrado-zesty2:~$ uname -a
Linux corrado-zesty2 4.9.0-1-generic #2-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 14 21:43:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
corrado@corrado-zesty2:~$
```

Comment: 17.04 is still in development and not officially released yet, so bugs are to expect. Please [report them on Launchpad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) instead of posting a question here.

Answer (score 1):

As [I have said before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303302/5132):

## This is not a bug.

What you describe is intentional on the parts of the Debian people.

You are not supposed to control samba services this way on a Debian/Ubuntu systemd operating system.  You are supposed to manipulate the `smbd`, `nmbd`, and `samba-ad-dc` services as needed.

There is no umbrella `samba.target` to do the original job of the old Debian/Ubuntu `samba` van Smoorenburg `rc` script; which was starting/stopping these three en bloc.  Other people created them, for other systemd operating systems.  The Debian people did not.

So where you read Debian/Ubuntu doco saying things like

```
service samba action
```

remember that that is not an available thing any more, now that Debian Linux and Ubuntu Linux are systemd operating systems.

## Just to add to the confusion …

What the rest of the world outwith Debian knows as `samba.service` is called `samba-ad-dc.service` in the Debian world.  Similarly, `nmbd.service` and `smbd.service` are originally `nmb.service` and `smb.service` outwith Debian.

So where you read *generic* systemd operating system doco about samba talking about `nmb`, `smb`, and `samba` services, you must mentally perform the translation for Debian/Ubuntu, particularly for the latter name.

## Further reading

- Liang Guo (2014-03-06).  *[/etc/init.d/samba forbit systemd shutdown system](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=740942)*.  740942.  Debian bugs.
- *[Mask /etc/init.d/samba init script for systemd](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-samba/samba.git/commit/?id=8828d90daf00d46cb95086af5e417a0701b57575)*.  Ivo De Decker.  2014-10-24.
- Ivo De Decker (2014-10-24).  *[samba init script should not be started after upgrade](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=766690)*.  766690.  Debian bugs.
- Ivo De Decker (2014-11-15). *[samba: unit samba.service is masked](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=769714#10)*.  769714.  Debian bugs.
- Wulf C. Krueger (2010).  [`samba.target`](https://github.com/sunbing81/subi-exheres/blob/master/packages/net-libs/libsmbclient/files/systemd/samba.target)